# Random Greeting Generator

Tags: php, html

Evening. Trying to get this random greeting generator to work. At first I didn't have the array for the $greet variable but they I was getting errors saying I hadn't defined the variable. Now I am getting an Array to string conversion error. Any thoughts?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//store random greetings

$greet = array('Hello','Welcome','Greetings!','Salutatons!','Good day!', 'Yo!');

switch($greet){

case 1: 
  $greet = 'Hello!'; 
  break;
  case 2: 
  $greet = 'Welcome!'; 
  break;
case 3: 
  $greet = 'Greetings!'; 
  break;
case 4: 
  $greet = 'Salutations!'; 
  break;
case 5: 
  $greet = 'Good day!'; 
  break;
case 6: 
 $greet = 'Yo!'; 
 break;
}
echo $greet;

//set the seed for mtrand with the number of microseconds
//since the last full second of the clock

mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
//computes a random integer 0-4

$number=mt_rand(0,5);
echo $number;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I removed the portion that had the array. That was me just trying to figure this out a bit. I feel like I am already declaring the variables, but I get an error saying I'm not. Is it not technically declaring the variable within the Case statements?

Comment: Okay, so should I declare $greet = ' ' then take a look at my switch statement? I can review how those should work a bit more. To be honest I have rarely used switch and under close supervision. :-)

Comment: Take a step back and decompose the problem you're trying to solve - show a random greeting from a predefined list: 1. define array with different greetings (OK), 2. randomly select a greeting from array(NOT OK), echo greeting (OK). You seem to have forgot the random selection of your greeting. You don't need a switch block to do what you want. Check out [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Okay, I will take a look, but I do have to specifically incorporate "# Set the seed for mtrand with the number of microseconds
# since the last full second of the clock
mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
$number = mtrand(0, 4); # Computes a random integer 0-4" this portion. I can think of less complicated ways to go about this but I have to stick to certain requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `array_rand()` to get random keys from array. Not switch/case.

Look at the code below. Now `$greet` variable will override itself with a random greeting from the array.

```php
<?php
//store random greetings

$greet = array('Hello','Welcome','Greetings!','Salutatons!','Good day!', 'Yo!');

$greet = $greet[array_rand($greet)];

echo $greet;

//set the seed for mtrand with the number of microseconds
//since the last full second of the clock

mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
//computes a random integer 0-4

$number=mt_rand(0,5);
echo $number;
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you. I finally resolved a syntax error that was causing me to show nothing. Then got a number instead of a greeting. Your help got me a greeting and number. I removed the "echo $number;" section and it works perfectly. Thank you!!